# python - remove space in the end of range loop (int)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range

Its quite simple but I got stuck. I have two files who need to be identical(even spaces)

file #1 is the output from :

```py
for i in range(0, 19):
    print(i)
```

and the other is the same just without space after the 18

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
```

how do I remove the space after the 18 in order to get identical files?? ( only by changing file#1)

thank you! 
[the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWaAe.png)

Comment: How does output from `for i in range(0, 19): print(i)` contain space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: I don't think there are any spaces here, just line breaks. File #1 will contain line breaks after every number, essentially ending the file with an empty line. File #2 on the other hand ends at '18'

Answer (score 1):

You can call `print` with newline as the separator and an empty string as the end marker instead:

```
print(*range(19), sep='\n', end='')
```

Comment: doesnt work :(  it returns the range multiple times and 180 instead of 18

Comment: Please see demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/SneakyStunningKeychanger

Answer (score 1):

Try building the whole string first and then printing it:

```
m = " \n".join(map(str, range(19)))
print(m)
```

I recommend you use `join` because you can specify a character that will only be inserted between the letters (in this case the separator is `" \n"`) and not after the last one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be “0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.....18”, it should also include “try this end = " ," ”.

```
print(i, end=",")
```